# How to prevent the breaking of text by making the div(and its contents) smaller?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to lock the div at a particular size and beyond that size(smaller size screens), the div along with its contents should become smaller and preserve the viewing style.
In short, how do I prevent this:

[image]

turning into this:

[image]

here is the code: 
https://codepen.io/proxenon267/pen/wvadjxy

html:

```
<div class="content">
      <div class="boxy">
        <div class="a mw"><b>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ante metus dictum at tempor.</b> 
        </div>
        <div class="b mw">
          cidunt. Vulputate ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam. Lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim. Duis at consectetur lorem donec massa sapien faucibus et. Aliquam faucibus purus in massa tempor.
        </div>
        <div class="c mw">
           <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1580818302076-305ea44b738c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' width=250px height=150px>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

scss:

```
$height: 100px;
$width: 100%;
$border: double black;
$pad: 10px;
.content {
  border-top: $border;
  border-bottom: $border;
}
.boxy {
      display:flex;
      max-width: 100%;
    }
.a{
  min-height: $height;
  width: $width;
  padding: $pad;
}
.b{
  min-height: $height;
  width: $width;
  padding: $pad;
}
.c{
  min-height: $height;
  width: $width;
  padding: $pad;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  img{
  width:100%;
  }
  .b{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your expected outcome? The text has to go _somewhere_

Comment: as I have mentioned, I want the div along with its contents to become smaller beyond the fixed point.

Comment: then use media screen between like 100px to 300 px, decrease the font-size

Comment: So you want the font-size to decrease down to the point where you need a magnifying glass to read it?

Comment: I don't specifically want the font-size to decrease, I want the whole div with its contents to become smaller.

Comment: I still don't get it. How do you want to "shrink" the div, without reflowing the text or reducing the font size? As stated in my first comment, the text has to go _somewhere_ (even if somewhere is "become smaller")

Comment: well I didn't mention that I will absolutely not reduce the font size, if required. So there's that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to put text in box , add width to this box with `percentage` ,and set `font-size` with `percentage` also

hope this helpful.